# Multiple Mappers for the same class in different databases

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, multiple-databases

I am currently working on a Wikipedia API which means that we have a
database for each language we want to use. The structure of each
database is identical, they only differ in their language. The only
place where this information is stored is in the name of the database.

When starting with one language the straight forward approach to use a
mapping between the tables to needed classes (e.g. Page) looked fine.
We defined an engine and corresponding metadata. When we added a
second
database with its own setup for engine and metadata we ran into the
following error:

```
ArgumentError:
Class '<class 'wp.orm.types.pages.Page'>' already has a primary mapper defined.
Use non_primary=True to create a non primary Mapper.clear_mappers() will remove
*all* current mappers from all classes.
```

I found an [email saying that there must be at least one primary
mappe](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg08221.html)r, so using this option for all databases doesn't seem feasible.

The next idea is to use sharding. For that we need a way to
distinguish
between the databases from the perspective of an instance, as [noted in
the docs](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/browser/sqlalchemy/trunk/examples/sharding/attribute_shard.py):

> "You need a function which can return
>   a single shard id, given an instance
>   to be saved; this is called
>   "shard_chooser"

I am stuck here. Is there a way to get the database name given an
Object
it is loaded from? Or a possibility to add a static attribute based on
the engine? The alternative would be to add a language column to every
table which is just ugly.
Am I overseeing other possibilities? Any ideas how to define multiple
mappers for the same class, that map against tables in different
databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I asked this question on a mailing list and got this answer by Michael Bayer](http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/187b3c13fa49a069):

> if you'd like distinct classes to
>   indicate that they "belong" in a
>   different database, and you have very
>   clear lines as to how this is
>   performed, use the "entity_name"
>   concept described at
>   http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName
>   .  this sounds very much like your use
>   case.
>
> > The next idea is to use sharding. For that we need a way to
> >     distinguish
> >     between the databases from the perspective of an instance, as noted
> >     in
> >     the docs:
> >     "You need a function which can return a single shard id, given an
> >     instance to be saved; this is called "shard_chooser"
>
> horizontal sharding is a method of
>   storing many *homogeneous*   instances
>   across multiple databases, with the
>   implication that you're   creating one
>   big "virtual" database among
>   partitions - the main   concept is
>   that an individual instance gets
>   placed in different   partitions based
>   on some ruleset.    This is a little
>   like your use   case as well but since
>   you have a very simple delineation i
>   think the   "entity name" approach is
>   easier.

So the basic idea is to generate anonymous subclasses for each desired mapping which are distinguished by the *Entity_Name*. The details can be found in [Michaels Link](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName)